# Can we use a different certificate for an Xamarin forms Android App with same bundle id

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Android App that is transferred from a different Google play store Account to my play store Account.

1. Can I use a different certificate for the same App to upload a different version with the same bundle Id? (I don't have the previous certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the older keystore, or if you have the keystore but don't have the alias name and password needed to use it, you have to create a new app. Sorry, it's happened to me before and it sucks. You could try to ask Android to make an exception, but I don't think they'll entertain it.